# Put find word count result into a variable

Tags: bash, shell, variables, find, word-count

```
#!/bin/bash
find *.txt | wc -l;
```

this gives number of txt files. In my program how do I put this output into a variable say "count"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
count=$(find *.txt | wc -l)
```